# MySql in apache webserver

Tags: mysql, apache

Hi i am running a servlet program in which sql query was used to insert a record into a table in mysql. In ubuntu 14.04 LTS I am running eclipse, in that i have a configured the apache 7.0.57. I am getting a exception when i am running the servlet

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

this is my jdbc connectivity lines

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    Connection con=  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/hospital","root","root123");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
}
```

Comment: your problem is not in the code but in the user you are trying to connect as, check the user and the password and that the host is allowed to connect. In other words, the error comes from the database denying access, not from the code you are using

Comment: i have executed mysql command in the terminal correctly running

Answer (score -1):

What is the name of your DB? I think you never created a DB. You are trying to connect to a DB witch dosen't exist, or is your DB called hospital?

`conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/?user=root&password=rootpassword");
s = conn.createStatement();
int result = s.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE databasename");`

and then you can do all the funny stuff...

`jdbc:mysql://localhost/databasename`

or you have prilivage issue...and can be solved with

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Comment: my database name is hospital and i am executing query for inserting data into table name registration.

Comment: And one more thing is the same code working fine if i am connecting through normal java program (i.e. not a servlet program). Please help me to sort out this issue.